# Executing VBScript step by step in c#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I want to write a program is C# that will allow me to execute a vbscript step by step like I would do in a debugger. I know I can run vbscript by creating a new process class form System.Diagnostics but I was wondering if that will allow me to execute one line of vbs code at a time.

Background:We have this UI automation framework that generates vbscript based on the tests written in an excel file. This vbscript in turn make calls to a dll that performs actions on the application.

We want to get away from excel and put this automation framework in silverlight.

So what I need is an ability for the user to run though step by step  through that vb script like a debugger on an interpreter would.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to implement your own scripting host.  Don't know much about it, ought to be challenging in C#.  Start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z537xb90%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This sounds promising. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [MS ScriptControl](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/scripting/article.php/c15).

You should be able to execute your code line by line, however maintaining the state might be a challenge depending on how many variables are being used by the VBScript or if you are just making one distinct call per line.

Comment: thanks. I'll try this. yes maintaining state will be required as there are lots of variables!